# NuGet reinstallation of package not working

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to reinstall a NuGet package using

```
Update-Package –reinstall <packageName>
```

as per the [NuGet documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages)

But I'm getting an error message

> Update-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter
>   name 'reinstall'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're using an old version of NuGet. The -reinstall option was implemented in NuGet 2.1. Update your nuget to the latest version should fix your problem.